# Do interview brainteaser questions predict performance?

Tags: interviewing

In a [2013 NYT interview](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/20/business/in-head-hunting-big-data-may-not-be-such-a-big-deal.html?pagewanted=all), some Google guy said:

> On the hiring side, we found that brainteasers are a complete waste of time. How many golf balls can you fit into an airplane? How many gas stations in Manhattan? A complete waste of time. They don’t predict anything. They serve primarily to make the interviewer feel smart.

It seems that many companies still continue asking such brainteaser questions, so is the above quote correct? What research is there on this matter?

Should companies continue this practice?

Edit: I'm hoping to get more general answers, and not just for interviews for programming or tech jobs. E.g. I hear that i-banks like Goldman Sachs like these puzzles too. So do some college admissions interviewers. Do they work?

Comment: These questions are designed to show if an applicant has skills in critical thinking and abstract thought.  It's supposed to reveal if an applicant can realize the pertinent variables and come up with a reasonable algorithm to approach the problem with.  It's not about getting the "correct" answer.  The problem is while applicants "pass" this test, managers "fail" because the point of this exercise has been lost.

Comment: I think this is part of Google's internal research. The discovered there was more consistency in some of their managers to pick candidates rather than all the different tests they gave. Not sure how rigorous the science is behind this "study" but you have to think they're pretty good with the numbers.

Comment: Remember that many companies do a piss-poor job of actually training their interviewers. (I'm very aware of this because IBM actually does have a good set of training materials, but despite sometimes being forced to do technical interviews I can't access most of that because I'm not a manager. Grr.)

Comment: These questions are designed to show if an applicant has the patience to put up with mindless requests that this company likely will inflict upon the candidate upon being hired. I like when companies ask questions like this. Makes it really easy for me to decide I don't want to work there. :)

Comment: Well, if it was a Google employer asking such a question I'd *definitely* answer: "Wait 30 second, I'll just google-that-for-you". Really, *this* is the optimal algorithm to start solving a new problem: search about it.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Google still asks estimation questions, cf the comments in this quora thread:  https://www.quora.com/Does-Google-still-ask-estimation-questions-to-Product-Manager-candidates

Answer (score 42):

> It seems that many companies still continue asking such brainteaser
>   questions, so is the above quote correct? What research is there on
>   this matter?

I examined this practice years ago. There has never been any research which indicates that these sorts of brainteaser questions can predict performance on the job. (Please - someone post reputable research results which prove me wrong! I could never find any.)

This practice is like many in the corporate world - a fad, popularized in some large companies (Microsoft famously), then followed unquestioningly by others who decided to follow the popular fad, or what some considered a "best practice".

I worked at one company where one of the principal developers used to ask candidates how they would go about finding a needle in a haystack. He claimed it "gave insight into how the candidate thought". When I questioned him a bit it turned out that he was asked this question during an interview once and thought it was clever - thus he decided to be clever and repeat it. When pressed, he admitted that it gave him no real insight. And of course he had no data that indicated it had any predictive value.

Many interviewers will rationalize their approach to interviewing. "It's for testing the candidate under stress conditions." "It's for insight into how they think." "It tells me if they are good at approaching ambiguity." But I agree with Google's conclusion - the actual primary purpose is to make the interviewer feel smart. It has no predictive value.

Comment: A major problem with such questioning is that many candidates will often have had exposure to some kinds of problems which others have not; while candidates who have had exposure to more different kinds of problems might be preferable to those who haven't, giving a programmer three problems to solve would be like trying to judge the sugar concentration in a solution by picking three molecules at random and classifying each as water, sucrose, or something else.  While concentrated sugar solutions would, on average, yield more sugar molecules than dilute ones...

Comment: ...it would be entirely possible for a relatively-dilute solution to yield two sucrose molecules and one water, or for a relatively-concentrated solution to yield only one sucrose but two water.  For results to really be meaningful, it would be necessary to sample a candidate's ability to handle an impractically-large number of semi-obscure problems.  If that isn't possible (it generally won't be), a better approach is to ask about problems which any reasonable candidate should be able to solve without having to exploit any obscure knowledge.

Comment: Out of interest, did you find solid research as to whether *any* interview questions, of any kind, predict performance on the job?

Comment: +1.  I think partly companies ask these questions so they can be convince themselves that they have done due diligence by following an industry standard (as you say), and to make everyone at the company feel like they have a more elite filtering process.

Comment: @SteveJessop that's actually a good question! I can't say I've ever interviewed anyone myself and thought about productivity specifically. It was usually more along the lines of "Are they competent? Do I like them? Will they fit in?" and just assume that they'll be productive.

Comment: @DA: well, if they're incompetent, you don't like them, and they don't fit in, then it's pretty likely they won't be productive. So your questions quite likely do predict performance (in that there's a statistically significant difference between the performance of people who give "good" answers vs "bad" ones). I'm just curious whether this is studied. If the effectiveness of different kinds of question isn't much studied, then absence of evidence for this particular kind of question isn't persuasive :-)

Comment: *How to find a needle in the haystack*: **Step 1**, Ignite the haystack. **Step 2**, Sweep a strong magnet over the ashes. **Step 3**, I get the job?

Comment: @SteveJessop, that's the real question. As important as evaluation of candidates is, there is very little available information on how to select candidates. I think this is because it is an intrinsically "soft skill" that requires subjective judgment. If there was a truly successful "system" we would have heard about it by now. This doesn't stop bloggers and certain HR professionals from promoting pseudo-scientific "shortcuts" to hiring like quizzes, puzzles, and personality-tests.

Comment: @teego1967: if it is an inherently soft skill, then there might well be questions that appear completely stupid because in the hands of someone who knows how to interpret the candidate's response, they can be used to find good candidates (or more likely, can be used to rule out a subset of the bad ones), whereas for anyone else to ask the same question is sheer cargo-cult :-) I'm not defending these questions, but that's certainly consistent with "it's not whether you get the right answer, it's how you approach the question".

Comment: Does "good at approaching ambiguity" mean you're unwilling to answer without more context, or willing to proceed without it?... or meh?

Comment: I don't agree the haystack question is stupid.  It already shows you something if someone just refuses to answer it versus if s/he eagerly jumps in with several suggestions (indicates a propensity for brainstorming or playful thinking, which can be important in certain roles).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, that is *your* question (and to be fair, the OP's).  Your colleague claimed it gave him "insight".  I doubt he or most people interviewing claim they are predicting "future performance" (perhaps just as nebulous a concept as "insight").   I think most interviewers are evaluating people on fit and seeing if s/he has certain capabilities appropriate for the role.

Answer (score 14):

The whole point behind this type of exercise is that they wanted developers who are good at estimating how much in terms of resources it takes to perform any task - You probably always want to be estimating how long a task will take because you don't want to be caught trying to do something in a way that take 10000 as much time as some other procedure.

Having said that, Google dumped this kind of question for interviews. Most likely because this kind of question is no predictor of performance on critical tasks like working out how to implement the specifics of virtualization as a way to get systems quickly on their feet and in particular, implementing the coding necessary to implement systems reliability. Google is VERY data driven and if Google is dumping it, Google is not saying so casually.

Google is probably better off asking the kind of questions that probe how a candidate approaches and solves problems rather than (unwittingly) play puzzle games. They want problem solvers not puzzle addicts. And that's to their credit.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes and no. If you go for a management consulting job as a junior/no management consulting experience, then this is a nice way to gauge your thought process. Also, to tell how well you've prepared for the interview. It won't quite be "golf balls in an airplane", more "How many passengers fly through JFK in a calendar year?"

It can also be used as a stress test - how fast can you think on your feet, are you capable of coming up with something coherent on the spot, or do you struggle?

While Google might not do the *particular* brand of puzzle question indicated, it is hardly accurate to say they don't do those questions at all. Google programming questions are just as "unfair" as any puzzler question you might be asked. As ever, prepping for the interview you're going to get is required. *Don't* expect "what is the difference between finally, finalize and final?"

Even Google non-programming questions still fall into the same "puzzler" style, just more in Google's style. Think "how would you work out which are the only two people in a room of people who can speak Spanish, when nobody has the same language as you (and you don't know Spanish)" stuff.

It can be used to gauge abstract thought, stress handling, interview preparedness - it is still a "good" interview question for what it says about you, the candidate, in terms of non-technical knowledge.

Comment: Hi @Davor, your comments here do not meet standards of professionalism expected for the Workplace. Please read [this link](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322) for more information if you have any questions.

Comment: @enderland - Oh I do have a question. Who determines what arbitrary standard of nice do we follow?

Comment: @Davor use [this post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322) if you have questions, comments, or want to discuss the policies for Stack Exchange and The Workplace. Additionally, if you have questions regarding "what should comments be used for?" please see [this post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2970/2322) or this [more lengthy post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72/2322). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When chatting with one Googler about a year ago (might be more already) on their hiring policy he was sharing how Google at some point ran a crazy huge survey with lots of different questions through all of Google (or at least those who had been in their ranks for awhile). Next they had people fill out the same survey and they started systematically figuring out using raw statistics which questions most distinctly defined a Googler a Googler. Why? Because they figured that their current employees fit best in their company and thus questions that where answered by all the same where worthless to ask.

Now, assuming that this statement was a consequence of that research then we can conclude that at least brainteasers are worthless to differentiate between high level employees. I assume that it *does* allow differentiation between just any and a truly bad candidate, but the same could be observed in a million easier ways as well.